# Need help finishing C program calculator with command line arguments

Tags: c, command, arguments, line, calculator

This program just needs to be able to identify the invalid arguments such as having a letter in the command line or a double operator, except 5--5 that would give you 10. Order of operations does not matter it just reads left to right. The code below only give a 0005 if the first argument is a 5, I cannot figure out how to get the code to do the operations. Thank you for any input as this will definitely help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  

    int op = 0;
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    double result = 0;

    for (int x = 1; x < argc; x++) {

        int num = atof(argv[x]);

        if (num ==! argv[x]) {
            printf("Invalid Input");
        }

        switch (atoi(argv[x])) {
            case'+': 
                op = 43; /* ASCII value of '+' */
                break;
            case'-':
                op = 45; /* ASCII value of '-' */
                break;
            case'*':
                op = 42; /* ASCII value of '*' */
                break;
            case'/':
                op = 47; /* ASCII value of '/' */
                break;
            case'^':
                op = 94; /* ASCII value of '^' */
                break;
            default:
                if (op == 0) {
                    num1 = atof(argv[x]);
                } else {
                    switch(op){
                        case 43:
                            printf("%.1d + %.1d = %.1d",num1, num2, num1+num2);
                            break;
                        case 45:
                            printf("%.1d - %.1d = %.1d",num1, num2, num1-num2);
                            break;
                        case 42:
                            printf("%.1d * %.1d = %.1d",num1, num2, num1*num2);
                            break;
                        case 47:
                            printf("%.1d / %.1d = %.1d",num1, num2, num1/num2);
                            break;
                        case 94:
                            printf("%.4d ^ %.4d = %.4d",num1, num2, num1/num2);
                            break;
                        default:
                        break;
                    }
                }

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `num ==! argv[x]` ? What's meaning?

Comment: It would help everyone, especially yourself, if you formatted the code properly including proper indentation. Then you might see that the `return` statement is inside your `for` loop. Which means the program will exit after just the first iteration.

Comment: This is some of what our teacher gave us to start with and what I've been trying to add in to get it to compile. What do you mean proper indentation? like with the brackets? The num ==! argv[x] is the code our teacher gave us to eliminate inputs with letters in them to compare the input to atof change to indicate invalid input